# trying to create a GX model for PolicyPeriod entity

Tags: gosu, guidewire

I am trying to create a GX model for PolicyPeriod entity.  When I try to test it using Gosu scratch pad it takes lot of time to execute/display output (10 to 15 mins).  Is there a better way of testing this:

I am trying to check the `transformedpayload`

Code:

```
var transformedPayload = (new policyperiodmodel.PolicyPeriod(aPolicy).asUTFString())
print(transformedPayload )
```

Comment: It should definitely not take that long.  I have not started working with GW8 yet, but a very large policy period xml only takes a few seconds.  Are there any errors in your studio console?

Comment: It got resolved.The problem was with the debugger, after setting the class path to \modules\out\classes it worked now it only takes few miliseconds. Thanks you.

Comment: @srihari: you may want to post your result as an answer for future readers.